# Pages refreshing into each other (chained-caller)

Tags: php, html, refresh

What will happen if

**index.php** is programmed to refresh (redirected) into **index2.php** after few seconds 
and
**index2.php** is programmed to refresh (redirected) into **index.php** after few seconds

will they keep calling each other endlessly without problem or will some server/browser memory will get flooded and make it crash ?

'preserve browser history' is turned off by default so browser will not try to remember previous URLs (page history)

Comment: curious, what is your use-case?

Comment: In Google Chrome I have seen `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` message.

Comment: @Karthikeyan You could have added this as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @Todd (1) My host does not allow me to add cron job less than 15 minutes so if I want one minute crons I can use this. Why not keep refreshing same page, you may ask, because second php's process is dependent on processing done by first php, second will return control to first php for further processing. That is the use case.

Comment: @HeenaShah it's specific to chrome I would have answered if I known what happen in most of the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that most modern browsers will pick this up as a redirect loop very quickly.

Tested with no `sleep`, and Chrome picks it up instantly.
Tested with `sleep(1)`, and Chrome gave the redirect loop error in about 5 seconds).